Epson Stylus problem LTS 24.04
Having an issue very similar to this question but for an Epson. The printer has worked with my previous machines and even on this new install, only intermittently. Settings -> printers is showing the printer as being successfully installed. When I order a print job, I get a message telling me the document was printed, but dead silence on the printer side. Anyone have a fix for this? Using LTS 24.04. Comfortable with using the terminal but not a power user. Thank you kindly :)

Maybe something from the posts below helps. I can't comment.
I had the same problem (although I use ubuntu cinnamon 24.04 and have EPSON L210). I installed the driver from epson's website, albeit it was commented that it was for ubuntu 20.04.
Then used sudo apt install printer-driver-escpr, deleted the icon form the "Add printer" wizard in preferences, added it back again and now it prints.
Printer connected properly, but can't print
How to install Epson L220 printer
It might also be helpful  for scanning to know this answer.

With Epson it might be beneficial to install the linux drivers provided by them.
That said I could print without the need of the drivers, but I find it works better with them.

That should hopefully fix the issue.
